# How to restrict the duplicate like urls from crawling

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

Working on storm crawler 1.10 and ES 6.4.2. After the crawling process is finished when I check the records the crawler is grabbing **https** and **http** urls with same title and description how can I tell the crawler grab only either one of the url.

```
Title: About Apache storm
Description:A Storm application is designed as a "topology" in the shape of a directed acyclic graph (DAG) with spouts and bolts acting as the graph vertices. Edges on the graph are named streams and direct data from one node to another. Together, the topology acts as a data transformation pipeline. At a superficial level the general topology structure is similar to a MapReduce job, with the main difference being that data is processed in real time as opposed to in individual batches. Additionally, Storm topologies run indefinitely until killed, while a MapReduce job DAG must eventually end.
url: https://www.someurl.com


Title: About Apache storm
Description:A Storm application is designed as a "topology" in the shape of a directed acyclic graph (DAG) with spouts and bolts acting as the graph vertices. Edges on the graph are named streams and direct data from one node to another. Together, the topology acts as a data transformation pipeline. At a superficial level the general topology structure is similar to a MapReduce job, with the main difference being that data is processed in real time as opposed to in individual batches. Additionally, Storm topologies run indefinitely until killed, while a MapReduce job DAG must eventually end.
url: http://www.someurl.com
```

Answer (score 1):

These variants are often managed as redirections by the site so you'd get only one document. Alternatively, sites can provide [a canonical tag](https://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization) which StormCrawler uses as URL value if present.

StormCrawler sees the documents one by one in isolation and has no knowledge of other URLs. You could implement this outside of SC by :

1. collapsing the results when querying the index
2. deduplicate the content of the index for instance with MapReduce

One option within SC to deal with any remaining duplicates would be to generate a custom metadata e.g. a hash of the content and modify the ES Indexer bolt so that it uses that value if present [instead of the normalised URL](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/elasticsearch/bolt/IndexerBolt.java#L183) for the document ID. You'll then get a single doc but will have no way of choosing which one of the URLs to use (http or https).

Comment: Can we index the documents with out specifying http or https protocol like **www.someurl.com**.

Comment: Not without having the mechanism described above for using a custom metadata as doc Id